# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension Windows 7 32 Bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devkit

I am trying to install [json](https://rubygems.org/gems/json/versions/1.8.3) ruby gem on Windows 7 32 System.

The local environment details are

```
D:\Environment\DevKit32Ruby200>gem -v
2.0.14

D:\Environment\DevKit32Ruby200>ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]

D:\Environment\DevKit32Ruby200>rails -v
Rails 4.0.4
```

I have already tried following things

1. Downgrading system ruby gems version to 2.3.0 using

   ```
   gem update --system 2.3.0
   ```
2. I have done proper setting of devkit and manually I added proper ruby directory path in config.yml file.

   ```
   D:\Environment\DevKit32Ruby200>ruby dk.rb init

    Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
    'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
    of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

   D:\Environment\DevKit32Ruby200>ruby dk.rb install --force
       [WARN] Updating (with backup) existing gem override for                            'D:/Environment/ruby200new'
      [WARN] Updating (with backup) DevKit helper library for 'D:/Environment/ruby200new'
   ```
3. I have also tried putting platform=ruby

   ```
   gem install json --platform=ruby --verbose
   ```

The error I am getting while installing json is bellow.

```
D:\Environment\DevKit32Ruby200>gem install json
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    D:/Environment/ruby200new/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so

make "DESTDIR=" install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 generator.so ./.gem.20170109-8336-qvgvzc/json/ext
make: execvp: /usr/bin/install: Permission denied
make: *** [install-so] Error 127


Gem files will remain installed in D:/Environment/ruby200new/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-2.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Environment/ruby200new/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-2.0.2/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

There are 10's of questions are already tagged on this issue but none resolved.
Kindly help me to identify whats missing and why the error coming.

Comment: Please check your 'config.yml' file generated by 'ruby dk.rb init' command and check for installed ruby version and path

Comment: I manually added proper ruby directory path in config.yml and its no issue

Comment: Based on log it's look like issue is in ruby path but anyway try with gem install json --platform=ruby

Comment: got this error :

D:\APPS\LX_release7_JanPRD>gem install json --platform=ruby
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: Why are you doing this btw? There must be a *very* good reason to offer bounty on making JSON compile on MINGW ^_^

Comment: I had faced the similar issue,i did run command, gem update --system 2.3.0 ,i hope this gem version would not make trouble for your rest of the gems.

Comment: @Amit Agarwal thank you , I did already tried downgrading rubygem to 2.3.0 did not worked I mentioned in question as well.

Answer (score 2):

`i386-mingw32` is a mountain of pain that'll never be fully supported, when I spent time on Windows I used to use a VirtualBox VM with ubuntu installed which shares a folder with the Windows host. I would edit the files with netbeans in windows and run the code in putty, the VM would basically be headless.

I actually did a lot of *real* work that way. If you want to do a "Hello World" rails app - OK - good luck even with that. How about an online development environment such as https://c9.io/ ?

But if you want to *work*, not just play around, set yourself up with an Ubuntu VM at the very least, or work in Ubuntu/MacOS at the very best.

Comment: I second that. I also faced this error, and after a lot of unsuccessful attempts, I switched to Ubuntu. Things are running fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

Why don't you download the `json` .gem file from [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/downloads/json-2.0.3.gem) and install it directly using command

```
gem install json-x.x.x.gem
```